# Saving the tick in the checkbox isn't working after quiting and then returning to app

Tags: android

Hi I have got a tick box which i want the user to tick and and then to keep that tick saved when user leaves the app or navigate to different activity and returning.  This is the code of have got sofar but that doesn't seem to be working

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test_ticking, container, false);

    ch = (CheckBox) rootView.findViewById(R.id.TickBox1);
    ch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    SharedPreferences pref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("Pref",0);

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(pref.getBoolean("check", false))
            {
                ch.setChecked(false);
                pref.edit().putBoolean("check", false).commit();

            } else {
                ch.setChecked(true);
                pref.edit().putBoolean("check", true).commit();
            }
        }
        public void onResume() {
        }{

                if(pref.getBoolean("check", true))
            {
                ch.setChecked(false);

            } else {
                ch.setChecked(false);
            }
  }
 });

   return rootView;
  }
 }
```

Can any one assist me in this issue.  I don't think it can be that hard to get this to work?

Comment: why do you expect it to be checked when your _onResume_ calls _ch.setChecked(false);_ in both cases of the if-clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To store the preferences you could do something like this. Instead of using a onClickListener use a OnCheckedChangeListener:

```
ch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

            SharedPreferences pref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("Pref",0);
            if (isChecked) {

                pref.edit().putBoolean("check", true).commit();
            }
            else {

                pref.edit().putBoolean("check", false).commit();
            }
        }
    });
```

Your onResume method should be like this:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {

    super.onResume();
    SharedPreferences pref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("Pref",0);
    if(pref.getBoolean("check", false)) { 

        ch.setChecked(true); 

    } else { 

        ch.setChecked(false); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Indeed. But  ch.setChecked(false); and ch.setChecked(true); have to be removed from onClick() also. And onPause could be used to `pref.edit().putBoolean("check" true/false)';`

Comment: much appreciated! although when adding another checkbox i have to tap twice before it ticks the second boxs and twice again to untick.  any idea why its doing that?

Comment: I don't really know without seeing your code. But you should create a different pref and OnCheckedChangeListener for each CheckBox.